# How to fix Alexa exit command not working?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, alexa-skills-kit

I am building an Alexa skill and it is almost ready so I'm checking if all requirements are met in the certification tab in the Alexa console. Here I get the message that an error is thrown when a user says "exit". To fix it I added exit as a utterance in the stop intent but after I build and tried again it still doesn't work. I also have a utterance "stop" in the stop intent and this command does work. What am I doing wrong?

My code to catch a request to the stop intent:

```
case "AMAZON.StopIntent":
                        response = ResponseBuilder.Tell("Good bye.");
                        response.Response.ShouldEndSession = true;

                        return new OkObjectResult(response);
```

and my stop intent:
[image]

I've read about that an exit command doesn't need to be handled and that it will just cause a hard exit so I tried removing the exit utterance from the stop intent but I still get an error when I call exit in my skill.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake. I didn't catch SessionEndedRequests so I got the error.
Added code:

```
 if (skillRequest.Request is SessionEndedRequest)
            {
                response = ResponseBuilder.Tell("Good bye.");
                response.Response.ShouldEndSession = true;

                return new OkObjectResult(response);
            }
```